# Is there a way to create a django Template from a string with the configured backend?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

New to django, I am loading template from a string,

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import Template, Context

settings.configure()
a= Template(template_variable)
```

but getting exception:

```
"No DjangoTemplates backend is configured.")
ImproperlyConfigured: No DjangoTemplates backend is configured.
```

Comment: do you have a BACKEND set in settings? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#configuration The code you show here is a bit non-typical. Which file is it in?

Comment: try doing this from a view instead, preferably using `render()`